# Reading a variable from reader thread without holding up a writer thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, embedded, embedded-linux

I've got two threads, a reader thread and a writer thread. The writer thread writes a string and the reader thread reads the string. The writer thread is extremely high speed and I do not want to hold the writer thread up. The reader thread is much slower (a factor million or more slower) and it is not important if the read string is a couple of cycles behind. The only important thing for the reader thread is that when it reads the string that it's not in an undefined state.

Is there a way to be thread safe for reading the string without holding up the writing thread?

I've also looked at making the variable atomic, but I read that this might be a performance bottleneck as well for the writing thread.

Comment: if you have only one writer thread and multi reader thread it's okay to not put mutex on writer thread and it's thread safe already. but here is thing you said reader thread should only read when string is not in undefined state therefore you should some how notify reader thread that string is in valid state. you can achieve this by condition variables which is writer thread notify reader threads that string is in valid state so start reading or you can do busy loop on reader thread side(like spin lock).

Comment: How big can that string grow? If your writer is faster than your reader, your string will continuously grow (assuming both threads do work all the time). Also, is the string even consumed on read?

Comment: The string does not continually grow, to be honest it will be mostly integers. But occasionally it might be bigger. Too big that it can be processed in a single copy action.

Comment: 1. If the string doesn't grow, how can the writer be faster than the reader? Are we talking about a single string here or perhaps a collection of strings? 2. What do you mean by copy action?

Comment: 1. The writer thread writes every couple of micro seconds to a variable, the reader thread only reads the variable every couple of seconds or minutes. 2. It's on a 32 bit system, since it's a string it could be bigger than 32 bits, so it will take multiple copy actions to copy the value into the variable.

Comment: So the writer simply keeps overwriting the variable all the time, but when the reader reads it, the writer shouldn't be blocked, right? I still don't understand what you mean by copy actions. Do you just mean that multiple registers have to be copied / moved?

Comment: Also, which C++ version do/can you use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works but I come up with an idea:

Assume you have two string buffers, *Buffer_0* & *Buffer_1*, each can hold a single string of multiple characters of a predefined max length.

The writer thread alternates between two buffers, but it first checks a mutex. The writer doesn't block on the mutex, it just writes to the other buffer if the mutex is not available. This means that it stops alternating between two buffers and writes into the same buffer multiple times while the reader slowly reads the mutex protected buffer.

Buffer choice of the reader probably doesn't matter much. It can always try to read *Buffer_0*. It may simply block on the mutex and wait until the writer starts writing *Buffer_1*. While it reads from the *Buffer_0*, the writer always writes to *Buffer_1* over and over as it fails to acquire the mutex.

Of course, checking the availability, acquiring and releasing of the mutex introduces some run-time cost. Maybe, using an atomic variable which indicates the buffer index that the writer is currently writing into, may work faster than using a mutex. But I'm not sure if it works.

**Update:** I realized that in the above scenario, *Buffer_1* is mostly useless as the reader only reads from *Buffer_0*. If it's not acceptable for reader to block, it can alternate too and read *Buffer_1* instead of waiting. Or the writer can just skip the whole writing operation (writing to *Buffer_1*) if it's unable to acquire the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Are you OK with the reader reading a recent value and not necessarily the most recent one ? If so, you can use atomics :

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string spots[4];
std::atomic<int> canWrite;
std::atomic<int> readyIndex;

int writer()
{
    while(true) // for demonstration, will be your real writer loop
    {
        if (readyIndex != canWrite)
        {
            spots[canWrite] = "foo"; // write here what the writers wants to write
            readyIndex = canWrite + 0; // marks that spot as ready
        }
    }
}

int reader()
{
    canWrite = 0;
    while(true) // for demonstration, will be your real reader loop
    {
        if (readyIndex == canWrite)
        {
            std::cout << spots[readyIndex] << std::endl;
            canWrite = (canWrite + 1)  % 4; // allow the write to start writing at the next location
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(writer);
    std::thread r1(reader);

    t1.join();
    r1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The reader only writes to `canWrite`, telling the writer where it can write. The writer only writes to `readyIndex`, telling the reader where it can read.

If the reader has not read yet the latest string, the writer just skips and goes its merry way.

Comment: This assumes "writes a string" to mean writing a new string at every write, not appending to an existing string.